# Entity Framework Core 1:n relation causes a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core In-memory database. I have a problem with the definition of the foreign key (navigation property). One user could have multiple tokens. So my user table is called `Benutzer` and my token table is called `RefreshToken`:

```
public class Benutzer
{
    [Key]
    public int BenutzerId { get; set; }

    public string AnmeldeName { get; set; }
    public string Passwort { get; set; }
    public string BevorzugteSprache { get; set; }

    public byte[] Salt { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int Iterationen { get => 10000; }

    // Navigation property
    // [ForeignKey("BenutzerId")]
    public virtual List<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
}

public class RefreshToken 
{
    [Key]
    public int RefreshTokenId { get; set; }

    public string Token { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public virtual Benutzer Benutzer { get; set; } // <-- caused a loop
    
    [ForeignKey("BenutzerId")]  
    public int BenutzerId { get; set; } 
 }
```

Without the navigation property in table `RefreshToken`, it works partially. I can add a token for an user. If I request the user table, I get the attached tokens. But I can add a token with a `BenutzerId` which is not existing.

Now I added the navigation property to the `RefreshToken` table, see code above. That has caused a loop.

If I request the user table, I get the attached token, this one attached the user and so on. Further I can add a token with an none existing user.

What's wrong?

```
var list = await _dbContext.Set<Benutzer>().ToListAsync();
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: @MathewHD `Benutzer` has a one-to-many, and `RefreshToken` has a one-to-one.   Doesn't sound like there is anything wrong with that, to me.

Comment: *That has caused a loop.* how did you discover a loop? exception? where is stacktrace

Comment: Using a unit-test there is no exception, but I can see within debug, that there is a reference from one to the other table. Using my API controller I got a exception, because of this looping references, see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695980/using-entityframework-core-causes-jsonexception-on-api-controller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FK definition if on the FK property should point to the navigation property, or if on the navigation property, point to the FK:

```
public virtual Benutzer Benutzer { get; set; } 
[ForeignKey("Benutzer")]  
public int BenutzerId { get; set; }
```

or

```
[ForeignKey("BenutzerId")]  
public virtual Benutzer Benutzer { get; set; } 
public int BenutzerId { get; set; }
```

For EF Core you don't actually need the FK Property, you can leave it as a Shadow Property to avoid confusion where you might update a reference (Setting a Benutzer vs. changing BenutzerId)

This should work in EF Core with a shadow property:

```
[ForeignKey("BenutzerId")]  // No property declared for BenutzerId, EF will treat it behind the scenes.
public virtual Benutzer Benutzer { get; set; }
```

Comment: for first two cases you dont really need attribute, if you have Property and PropertyId, EF Core will "see" them as a FK automatically

Comment: mhhh. If I will not define the BenutzerId property I could not use it to add a Token like `await _dbContext.RefreshToken.AddAsync(new RefreshToken { Token = token, BenutzerId = id });` Maybe It is the wrong way?!

Comment: @WMY this answer is fine. you can use any approach listed in it. it is up to you. personally, I don't like "automatic" foreign keys, and I always specify them in model

Comment: Should it possible to add a token with a none existing BenutzerId. I think not, but it works here (using inMemory database)?

Comment: @WMY in memory database exists purely for testing, it does not implement constraints same as relational databases. when you will use this code with SQL Server, for example, EF Core migrations will generate foreign key for this case. So it won't be possible to insert non-existing key

Comment: Thanks for your help! To handle the rekursion I found out I have to set the  `[JsonIgnore]` on the navigation property to avoid an exception later.

Comment: Adding `[JsonIgnore]` may 'work', but it's not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the action navigation property, you have the FK but not the entity:

```
public class RefreshToken 
{
    [Key]
    public int RefreshTokenId { get; set; }

    public string Token { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public Benutzer Benutzer {get;set;} <<<<<<<<

    [ForeignKey("BenutzerId")]  
    public int BenutzerId { get; set; } 
 }
```

Comment: Sry, in my initial posting I forgot that line of code, which causes the problem!